# custom syntax in sublime 3

Tags: python, syntax, sublimetext3

Currently working for a company that is using their own programming language.
It comes close to python (thus I'm using this syntax), yet the only differences are e.g.:

- line comments being "initialized" by '..' (two dots)

Yet replacing python's syntax-file in the comments section from '#' to '..' makes it comment out pretty much everything.

I'm thinking there's some option further down the syntax-file colliding with this change.

`(line 404)`

```
comments: 
- match: '#'
  scope: punctuation.definition.comment.python
  push:
    - meta_scope: comment.line.number-sign.python
    - match: \n
      pop: true
```

Comment: That sounds like it's probably a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
- match: '\.\.'
```

In regular expressions, `.` matches any character, so `'..'` would match any two characters. With a a backslash, you escape it, making it match a literal period character only.

Comment: absolutely lo-ve-ly